# How to sqoop import append new data into partitoned hive table which creates new partitioned folder on same partitioned column? Below is my scenario

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop, partition

I have a partitioned table on date column in hive and can able to sqoop import data into hive partitioned table for the first time.
when i perform this it created all the date folders properly and data got loaded into each folder in hdfs location of hive table.
Now when I want to sqoop import and append the new data again into same hive table with new updated date (which creates new date partition folder in hdfs hive location)
and loads new data into table. How to perform this using sqoop import operation?

Answer (score 0):

Model your data in more manageable way . Use created date for the partitioning not updated date .In my knowledge hive doesn't support updating the partitions, there may be workarounds for that but it might be cumbersome. So use a field which is not going to change as a partition key. Are you using static partition for the first time sqoop import ? As far as I know sqoop import only support importing usnig static partitioning unless you use `hcatelog` . 
If you've got other solution please shere , I have got a similar situation and I solved as described above.